# Is a file created through MediaDevices.getUserMedia() saved on the user’s browser?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mediarecorder, getusermedia

I am using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia to record an audio clip. The user can play the audio clip and/or download it after stopping recording. Is this information stored in the user’s browser?

```
if ( navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === undefined ) {
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function ( constrains ) {
    var getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia
    if ( !getUserMedia )  {
        return Promise.reject( new Error( 'getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser' ) );
    }
```

I used [Robert Bakiev’s code](https://codepen.io/robert_bakiev/pen/VpoLYo), who is saving the file as a blob. [Web Dictaphone](https://mdn.github.io/web-dictaphone/) is similar.

I don’t want to store user’s recorded files on my server. If they leave it recording for hours and hours, it would take up too much memory. Also, it seems like an invasion of privacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Blob data that comes from getUserMedia via MediaRecorder is stored in the browser on your user's machine unless something you wrote sends it to a server.

For a user to get her hands on those Blobs it's necessary to download them. In the case of these Dictaphone-style apps they are not downloaded from any server, but rather from the browser itself into the user's Downloads folder (or wherever the user puts them.)

I've never left a MediaRecorder running for hours, but I know you can use up a browser RAM quota by doing that.